# Should I edit or re-ask my question?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

If I edit my question after attempting to fix a problem and the problem still exists does my question still get answered or do I have to re-ask the question?

Comment: Unless your edit says you have solved it, it should still be open for answers.

Comment: If your question isn't solved, you don't have to reask. Otherwise, your new question is likely to get closed as duplicate of your original one. Basic idea is that single issue should have single question. Of course that's not always the case, but that's what's the intention on this site and others on StackExchange network. What I'd suggest is either update sometimes, comment on you post time to time so that it's brought to main page and people see it, or offer a bounty on it.  Of course you need rep points for bounty ( minimum 50 ). But you also can ask others to help in this regard.

Comment: I see your recent WiFi question was closed as duplicate. Did solutions on duplicate work or not ? If not, it may be reopened. Alternatively, a bounty can also be offered on the duplicate referencing your post and that you're seeking an answer for your specific case

Comment: Solutions did not work. I edited my question however I have not received a response. This is why I asked the edit question. I will reopen. Thank you